# Is there a way to access a value of a JSON document from mongodb which is inside an ArrayList?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, arraylist

I have a code snippet that looks like this

```
MongoDatabase db = DbConnection.getDbConnection(); // connection is successfully made
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("candidates"); collection called candidates in the database

ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();

FindIterable<Document> findIterable =  collection.find()
    .projection(fields(include("CandidateId"), excludeId()));

for(Document document:findIterable) {
  newList.add(String.valueOf(document));            
  }
System.out.println(newList);
```

The output looks like this

```
[Document{{CandidateId=1}}, Document{{CandidateId=2}}]
```

Is there any way I could get an arrayList that looks like this, where i only need the value of the  CandidateId field

```
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Document::getString`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.2/org/bson/Document.html#getString-java.lang.Object-) like this:

```
newList.add(document.getString("CandidateId"));
```